# why there is no semicolon error in following php code

Tags: php

in below code there is no syntax error show in php but if try with out loop it gives me syntax error.

```
 while($i<5)
  {
    $abcd= 
   $i++;    
  }
```

I want to know why PHP is not giving me a syntax error.

Comment: Because you are assigning the value of $i to $abcd and then incrementing $i. It would be the same as writing `while ($i<5) { $abcd = $i; $i++; }`. Edit: Oh sorry, your title was a very different question than the question itself.

Comment: You mean why doesn't the IDE give an error? Because PHP will only give the error when you run it.

Comment: if thats all your code you should get a **notice of undifined index***

Comment: No repro: https://3v4l.org/MrQiK

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know why PHP is not giving me a syntax error

Because there is no syntax error. Line feeds (but also tabs and spaces) are irrelevant for the code syntax. There's also no strict requirement to have assignment in one line (even though it is highly recommended but that's mostly to make the code easily readable for humans). This in general applies to all the code, so if you hate your job :) you can instead of:

```
for ($i=0; $i<20; $i++) {
   printf("$i\n");
}
```

start writing:

```
for
(
$i
=
0
;
$i
<
20
;
$i
++
)
{
printf
(
"$i\n"
)
;
}
```

and it will all work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

```
while($i<5)
  { $abcd= 
   $i++;
  }
```

ok, this doesnt give an syntax error means you have difined variable $i before the loop.

and it wont give you an eror if you removed the loop

```
$abcd=
$i++;
```

is  correct. so there will be no syntax error in both situations , I tested the code in [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/)